# how to use the arrary of names in post method

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, post

```
<td class="widht200">
<input type="text" name="agg" size="2" disabled="disabled"/> </td><td class="widht200">
<input type="text" name="agg" size="2" disabled="disabled"/></td><td class="widht200"> 
<input type="text" name="agg" size="2" disabled="disabled"/> </td><td class="widht200">
<input type="text" name="agg" size="2" disabled="disabled"/> </td><td class="widht200">
<input type="text" name="agg"  size="2" disabled="disabled"/> </td><td class="widht200">
<input type="text" name="agg"  size="2" disabled="disabled"/> </td><td class="widht200">
<input type="text" name="agg"  size="2" disabled="disabled"/> </td>
```

i have wrote the code like this.. so now.. i need to  post this form.. and 
agg as an array in php code.. how can i do it..

i used..

```
$arr[] = $_POST['agg'];
```

but showed error...

Comment: please tell more about your requirement. Currently, your question is not meaningful.

Comment: simple.. i need that array name to be posted.. in the form so i may able to use the user inputs as array.. $arr = $_POST['agg'] and $arr[0] must represent the value in the first text field $arr[1] represent the second so on...

Answer (score 2):

You want to add a the brackets within your html like so:

```
<input type="text" name="agg[]"  size="2" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Then just assign it within php like normal:

```
$arr = isset($_POST['agg']) ? $_POST['agg'] : array();
```

But you should always have some defined name for your data as you will not know what is what, try use like this:

```
<input type="text" name="agg[first]"  size="2" disabled="disabled"/>
```

then within php after you assign it you then can use `$arr['first'];`

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: agg in C:\wamp\www\final\index.php on line 9 i got this error when trying the same thing...

Comment: No, I mean that I have updated the php code above to fix that error.